# The purpose of the comma operator in JavaScript (x, x1, x2, …, xn)

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript `(x, x1, x2, …, xn)` always returns `xn`.

In Python this code is called tuple and it returns different values.

My question is what is the purpose of this code in JavaScript?
Do you have some practical example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comma operator evaluates every operand but only returns the result of the last evaluation. It can be used to initialize multiple variable in a for loop.

```
var str = "Hello, World!";
for(var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++)
    console.log(str.charAt(i));
```

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, this isn't a true example of the comma operator, this is just the `var`. You can see [this page](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/) for actual examples.

Comment: For reference, it is described in [§11.14](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_11.htm#Section_11.14) of the ECMA-262 spec.

Comment: Technically, your example of the 'comma operator' doesn't use the comma operator, even though it contains the comma symbol. That's a `var` statement, which takes the form `var name1 [= value1][, name2 [= value2][, ...]];` but uses the comma symbol differently to the actual comma operator. The actual comma operator evaluates and forms an *expression*, which the `var` statement does not.

Comment: Indeed. Edited post with real examples.

Answer (score 6):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Like in C and C++, the comma operator evaluates both the left and right operands, returning the right operand. In terms of practical uses, `a, b` can be used in place of `a ? b : b`, as well as used as a limited way to fit multiple 'statements' into one statement, such as in the first or third parts of a `for` loop.

Note that declaring and/or defining multiple variables with `var`, separated by commas, is **not** a use of the comma *operator*, even though it uses the comma *symbol*. The comma *operator* evaluates to and forms an *expression*, which can be used as a value as part of a larger expression or statement. `var` is a complete statement type that takes the form

```
var name1 [= value1][, name2 [= value2][, ...]];
```

Comment: Wow -- that ternary operator is the epitome of pointless. Better to just write `a; b;`, or if you need to assign a variable, `a; var whatever = b;`

Answer (score 2):

The [MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator) has a good example of a practical use for the comma operator:

> If a is a 2-dimensional array with 10 elements on a side, the following code uses the comma operator to increment two variables at once. The code prints the values of the diagonal elements in the array:

```
for (var i = 0, j = 9; i <= 9; i++, j--)
  document.writeln("a[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + a[i][j]);
```

Comment: Please note that in your example, only `i++, j++` is a use of the comma **operator**. `var i = 0; j = 9;` is not a use of the comma **operator**, even though it contains the comma **symbol**.