# Strange Javascript Feature: (5,2) == 2

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The purpose of the comma operator in javascript (x, x1, x2, …, xn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927685/the-purpose-of-the-comma-operator-in-javascript-x-x1-x2-xn)

In Javascript `(5, 2)` gives `2`, `('a', 'b', 'c')` gives `'c'` etc. (just try it out in the console).

My questions concerning that:

- Is there a reason for that "feature"?
- In which cases may it be useful?

Comment: It's called the "comma operator": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking at the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.
>
> You can use the comma operator when you want to include multiple
>   expressions in a location that requires a single expression. The most
>   common usage of this operator is to supply multiple parameters in a
>   for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! :)